# Symbolic link perl

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I create a file called `test.pl`.

I changed the permission mode for chmod u+x :

```
chmod u+x test.pl
```

I created a symbolic link to it:

```
ln -s path/test.pl test
```

After, I tried to run `test`, but it's interpreted as bash script. It gives an error.

Do you know why please?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate shebang (eg `#!/usr/bin/perl`) in the first line of test.pl?

Answer (score 9):

`test` is a built-in command.

To execute a command named `test` in the current directory, specify a (relative or absolute) path:

```
$ ./test
```

In addition, you need to have [`#!/usr/bin/perl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on the first line of the script, so that the system knows how to execute it.

Answer (score 5):

Your script must have a shebang line, i.e. a first line containing the interpreter to be used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#... your script content here.
```

So the shell knows how to interpret it.

Best practice btw is to use `env` to determine your current version of perl, especial when using `perlbrew` or similar tools which install their own perls besides the system ones.